# SQL query results show not all results

Tags: mysql

I have a Table named Events, with some filed, among which there are "status" and "type". I want to show, in the join with a table Hosts, for every host, the status for every events of the current day, based on the event type.

So, for example, if I have this situation (list of hosts and how many events, distinct for type, there are):

```
Host: Achille. Types: 1 'OS', 1 'File Integrity', 1 'Running Services'
Host: Aiace. Types: 1 'Running Services'
Host: Ulisse. Types: 1 'File integrity'
```

using this query:

```
SELECT distinct h.name, 
    (case when e.type = 'File Integrity' then e.status end) as FI, 
    (case when e.type = 'Running Services' then e.status end) as RS,
    (case when e.type = 'Services' then e.status end) as S,
    (case when e.type = 'OS' then e.status end) as OS
FROM hosts h
JOIN events e ON h.id = e.host_id 
WHERE DATE(e.date) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY h.name;
```

I got these results:

[image: Table]

where, for Achille, only the status of the OS event is shown; why?
I add that, inserting the events, the one with type = 'OS' was the first one added.

Comment: You lost me at 'wanna'

Comment: It only shows the first row because you are using **GROUP BY **

Comment: If you have `group by` you dont need `distinct`. But show us your complete sample data. What is the result of your query with `SELECT *  ...` without group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you aren't aggregating the status

```
SELECT  h.name, 
        MAX( case when e.type = 'File Integrity' then e.status end ) as FI, 
        MAX( case when e.type = 'Running Services' then e.status end ) as RS,
        MAX( case when e.type = 'Services' then e.status end ) as S,
        MAX( case when e.type = 'OS' then e.status end ) as OS
FROM hosts h
JOIN events e ON h.id = e.host_id 
WHERE DATE(e.date) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY h.name;
```